# How to store the contents of an array into a file inside an awk program?

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, unix, awk

I have this array inside an awk program. I want to store this array into a file to do some other manipulations at a later point of time. Can you pls help?
Its much appreciated if someone shows a simple one line awk program to do this task..
Basically i have a file with some 30+ lines with each line containing data in following format--
text1;[[tag]];tag_comments

My script only extracts the tag and stores it in an array.

```
 BEGIN{
    tags_file = "tags.dat";
    tag_cnt = 0;
    while(getline x < tags_file > 0){
    n = split(x,a,/\;/);
    if(n >= 3){
      tag_stripped = substr(a[2],3,length(a[2])-4)
      tag[tag_cnt] = tag_stripped;
      tag_cnt++;
      }
    }
    close(tags_file) 
    }  

EXAMPLE of file--line 1--john;[[smith]];john is a vegetarian  
line 2- mark;[[henry]];mark henry is a wrestler  
line 3- john;[[travolta]]; john travolta has acted in Pulp fiction.  
etc....
```

Here i am extracting smith, henry and travolta and storing them in an array. I want to store the contents of this array in a text file to do further processing as i am calling this awk script from another shell script.

Comment: it will help if you provide a sample input and what you want to extract from this file.  The arrays in `awk` is populated from the input file.  Basically you want to extract some information from your input file but not clear what it is...

Comment: "My script only extracts the and stores it in an array. " ? Yes? It seems like a word is missing there. We need sample input and expected output from that input. Make the data so it is 40=60 chars per line and can easly be copy/pasteable. If 1 line of sample data covers all cases you need to handle, then only include 1 line (and the expected output). Good luck.

Comment: Why make it the reader's job to copy content into `tags.dat`, instead of having your script read from stdin and pass your content in a heredoc (to make it runnable by copy/paste with no prior setup)?

Answer (score 1):

in the inner `if` in your program:

```
if(n >= 3){
  tag_stripped = substr(a[2],3,length(a[2])-4)
  tag[tag_cnt] = tag_stripped;
  tag_cnt++;
  }
```

You can just add the following:

```
print tag_stripped > tag_output
```

see [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Redirection). This seems to be reimplementing what `awk` does *inside of* awk, though. Is the following what you are aiming for, or is a lot missing from the example above?

```
~$> cat test.input 
john;[[smith]];john is a vegetarian  
mark;[[henry]];mark henry is a wrestler  
john;[[travolta]]; john travolta has acted in Pulp fiction.

~$> awk -F'(\\[\\[|\\]\\])' '{ print $2 }' test.input >test_output

~$> cat test_output 
smith
henry
travolta
```

Also, maybe `sed` would be ok:

```
sed 's/^[^[]*\[\[//; s/\]\][^]]*$//;' test.input >test.output
```